# DynamicJasper: Using crosstab with Image

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I want to create dynamic report with *DynamicJasper* (*JasperReports*).

I used *DJCrosstab* for getting Dynamic column.

```
DJCrosstab djcross = new CrosstabBuilder()
  .setHeight(500)
  .setWidth(500)
  .setHeaderStyle(mainHeaderStyle)
  .setDatasource("sr",DJConstants.DATA_SOURCE_ORIGIN_PARAMETER,
DJConstants.DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_COLLECTION)
  .setUseFullWidth(true)
  .setColorScheme(DJConstants.COLOR_SCHEMA_WHITE)
  .setCellBorder(Border.THIN())
  .addRow("", "id", String.class.getName(), false)
  .addRow("", "loc", String.class.getName(), false)
  .addRow("", "status", String.class.getName(),false)
  .addColumn("", "name", String.class.getName(),false)
  .addColumn("", "section", String.class.getName(), false )
  .addColumn("","label",String.class.getName(),false)
  .addMeasure("value", String.class.getName(), 
DJCalculation.FIRST,"value", measureStyle)
  .setCellHeight(60)
  .setCellWidth(100)
  .setRowHeaderWidth(100)
  .setRowStyles(colAndRowHeaderStyle, totalStyle, totalHeaderStyle)
  .setColumnStyles(colAndRowHeaderStyle, totalStyle, totalHeaderStyle)
  .build();

drb.addHeaderCrosstab(djcross);
DynamicReport dr = drb.build();
```

But Now I want to add dyanmic image at this report.

So I am trying to use:

```
.addImageColumn("IMG", "image", 50, true,ImageScaleMode.FILL_PROPORTIONALLY ,style)
```

But `.addImageColumn` is not supported for *DJCrosstab*

So please let me know that how can I add image to *DJCrosstab*?